# JS - WebAuthn - Support for uvm extension?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, safari, webauthn

I've been wanting to detect whether a user uses a PIN instead of biometrics on my website that utilizes Webauthn, or even disable PIN altogether. I've read that this can only be done using the uvm extension. I've implemented it like this in the `publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions`, but I was not able to get it to work:

`extensions: {  uvm: true  },`

Why is this? Is it because no browsers/authenticators support the uvm extension? I thought at least Chrome and Edge supported it. And if not, why? Are there any workarounds to detect/disable PIN in webauthn?

Comment: As of my knowledge up to 2021, there might be limited support for the UVM extension in browsers. This could be the reason why your implementation is not working as expected.